# How to check if first 10 characters are the same from date options

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, jquery-ui

I'm trying to get it to hide the dates that do not match the datepickers selected date. So in order to do this i'm thinking to check the value of the first 10 characters because as you could see in the console:

Date 2018-01-20T05:00:00.000Z

2018-01-25 08:00:00 10:00:00

the date1 object and the select options text have the same structure for the first 10 characters

```
 var dateToday = new Date();
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            showButtonPanel: true,
            minDate: 1,
            maxDate: 28,


            onSelect: function(date){
                 var date1 = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');

                 $("#pow > option").each(function() {
                     if (this.value != date1) {
                        console.log(date1)
                        console.log(this.text)
                     }
                 });

            }


        });
    });
```

Comment: One of those dates is UTC, the other is local so the date will be different during the period of the offset even though they are on the same local day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if two strings start with the same 10 characters, just use:

```
if (date1.substring(0,10) === date2.substring(0,10)) {
}
```

Comment: If you don't mind, how would I be able to hide (using .hide im assuming) that which is iterated upon and passes the if test

Comment: You iterate in jQuery with `each`.

Comment: i got that part as you can see in the code. im currently trying this "$(this.value).hide();" but it wont work. I also tried $(this).hide(); but it just got rid of the entire select

Comment: you need to use `$(this).hide()`